# Safe cross-platform function to get normalized path

Tags: c, security, normalization, relative-path

I'd like to have a standard function that will convert relative paths into absolute ones, and if possible I'd like to make it as cross-platform as possible (so I'd like to avoid calling external library functions). This is intended so it's possible to prevent path exploitations.

I am aware that such a function wouldn't be able to detect symbolic links, but I'm ok with that for my application.

I could roll my own code, but there might be some problems with e.g. how a platform handles encoding or variations of the "../" pattern.

Is there something like that already implemented?

Comment: Does cross-platform imply Windows?

Comment: it would be great if it did! : ) 
But still, any solution pointing to the right path is good!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a single, universal function you can call, since there's no such function in the C or C++ standard libraries.  On Windows, you can use [`GetFullPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  On Linux, Mac OS X, and other *Unix-based systems, you can use the [`realpath(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html) function, which as a bonus also resolves symbolic links along the way.

Beware: Any solution to this is only reliable in a single-threaded program.  If you're using multiple threads, another can go out and change the working directory out from under you unexpectedly, changing the path name resolution.

Comment: that solved it! It would be better if I had an implementation that is independent of extra libs, as I could use the same pattern for inexistent paths, like remote paths, for example

Comment: @Waneck: Neither of these use extra libraries—`GetFullPathName` is part of kernel32.dll, and `realpath(3)` is in the C library, so unless you're doing something unusual like not linking in standard libraries, you're fine.  I'm also not sure what you mean by non-existent remote paths—both of these return errors if the path doesn't exist, and both should be able to handle network paths (e.g. NFS/AFS in the case of Unix, or UNC paths in the case of Windows).

Comment: Unfortunately realpath does require the path to exist, it does not work with any virtual path to do the .. and . handling.

Comment: For `GetFullPathName`, in addition to resolving the working directory, ".", and ".." components (as text; not by resolving symlinks, junctions, etc), it also implements DOS path normalization. It translates slash to backslash; strips trailing spaces and dots in the final component; and, for drive-letter paths, reserves DOS device names (i.e. NUL, CON, AUX, PRN, COM[1-9], LPT[1-9], and, in Win 8+, CONIN$ and CONOUT$) in the final component, where the name can be followed by any number of colons, dots, spaces, and even an extension (e.g. "C:\Temp\nul: . .txt" -> "\\.\nul").

Comment: If a Windows path starts with exactly "\\?\", don't pass it to `GetFullPathName` unless it's ok to translate slash to backslash (AFAIK only named pipes actually allow forward slash as a name character, since NPFS only supports a single root directory) and strip trailing spaces and dots from the name (e.g. "\\?\C:/file. . ." -> "\\?\C:\file").

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you're going to get to platform independence are the [POSIX libraries](http://cplus.kompf.de/posixlist.html).  In particular you'll wanna check out [unistd.h](http://cplus.kompf.de/posixlist.html#i12206609) which unfortunately I don't believe has a 'normalized' path concept.  If I remember correctly the standard itself doesn't even know much about directories much less relative ones.

To get better than that I think you'll need to roll your own path goodies.

Comment: I'd have no problem rolling my own solution, if I can guarantee that it would cover all cases. I'm not sure, for example, if there are any encoding gotchas that might still be vulnerable to attack