# Shorten path string function

Tags: c, windows, filepath, c-strings

I am curious if there is a previously written function for shortening a file path in a c string.

Example:

```
char* filePath1 = "\\folder1\\..\\folder1\\file.dat";
char* filePath2 = "\\folder1\\folder2\\..\\..\\folder1\\file.dat";
char* filePath3 = "\\folder1\\folder3\\..\\folder2\\..\\folder1\\file.dat";
```

I am wondering if there is a function that can recognize and reduce all of these strings to

```
char* allFilePaths = "\\folder1\\file.dat";
```

I don't have high hopes, but if there is a way to avoid rewriting existing (and hopefully well-tested) code, I am all for it!

Comment: Note that `\f` is a form-feed.  You probably intended to use `\\f` each time.

Comment: Do you want to do textual substitution or do you need to validate that `folder2` and `folder3` exist?  The system validates the names, but that involves more work than plain textual substitution.  It is very likely that there are Microsoft API functions to do the job.  I know I have Unix analogues of the code, both plain textual substitution and validating — though the validating code does more than just check that the names exist, and it handle symlinks too, which is a lot of fun.  (Also note that since the given strings are all string literals, you can't reliably modify them in situ.)

Comment: I did mean ` \\ ` thank you for the correction! I want to do text substitution, as I am assuming all these folders exist. Do you have any idea what those Microsoft API functions might be? ( I am under the assumption that I won't be dealing with symlinks, but handling those would be even better)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the Windows API memorized (Unix is hard enough, but there's less to remember on the whole).  You can search as well as I can, and you have more motivation to do so than I do.  I'd probably use `site:msdn.microsoft.com` as part of the Google search term.  For the rest, 'clean file path' might help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your help. Before I go off digging through the Window's API, do you have any idea what kind of name it might be under. I don't even know the words to describe this process any better than "shorten path" and that hasn't brought up anything for me. It might help improve my search time drastically.

Comment: Not a Windows expert; no access to a Windows system.  I really can't help more.  You're welcome to wait around and see if anyone else can provide pointers for you.

Comment: You could use the command `system` to execute the Windows parallel to `pushd && cd <input_path> && pwd && popd` (And then concat the filename). I guess there's some Windows version to this. Not efficient (creating a new process) but solves your problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for the link to `_fullpath()` I didn't recognize before. Thinking twice about this: As the question was done (and answered by me) it doesn't mean that the path (to be processed) has necessarily to exist (or be resolvable) on the current system. Do you know how `_fullpath()` handle this? Digging further I found [`realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html) (similar for Unix-likes). The latter sounds for me that it may fail for non-existing paths (e.g. if I want to process a list of file paths not applicable to the local OS).

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into our source code and realized that my comment described the actual algorithm rather unprecisely. Therefore, I will provide a working sample instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void strTok(const string &text, char delim, vector<string> &tokens)
{
  for (size_t i = 0, j, n = text.size(); i < n; i = j) {
    while (i < n && text[i] == delim) ++i;
    j = text.find(delim, i);
    if (j > n) j = n;
    tokens.push_back(text.substr(i, j - i));
  }
}

string filePathResolve(string filePath)
{
  // make paths Unix-style
  for (char &c : filePath) if (c == '\\') c = '/';
  // consider UNC paths
  const char *root = "";
  if (filePath.length() >= 2 && filePath.compare(0, 2, "//") == 0) {
    root = "//"; filePath.erase(0, 2);
  }
  // split file path into list
  vector<string> list; strTok(filePath, '/', list);
  // remove all non-functional entries (occurrences of '//' and '/.')
  for (size_t i = list.size(); i--;) {
    if (list[i].empty() || list[i] == ".") list.erase(list.begin() + i);
  }
  for (size_t i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if (list[i] == ".." && list[i - 1] != "..") {
      list.erase(list.begin() + i - 1, list.begin() + i + 1);
      i -= 2;
    }
  }
  // rebuilt path from list
  filePath = root;
  if (list.size()) {
    filePath += list.front();
    for (size_t i = 1, n = list.size(); i < n; ++i) {
      (filePath += '/') += list[i];
    }
  }
  // done
  return filePath;
}

int main()
{
  string samples[] = {
    "\\folder1\\..\\folder1\\file.dat",
    "\\folder1\\folder2\\..\\..\\folder1\\file.dat",
    "\\folder1\\folder3\\..\\folder2\\..\\folder1\\file.dat",
    "\\.\\folder1\\..\\folder1\\file.dat",
    "folder1\\..\\folder1\\.\\file.dat"
  };
  for (string path : samples) {
    cout << "original: " << path << endl
      <<    "resolved: " << filePathResolve(path) << endl;
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Tested in VS2013 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
original: \folder1\..\folder1\file.dat
resolved: folder1/file.dat
original: \folder1\folder2\..\..\folder1\file.dat
resolved: folder1/file.dat
original: \folder1\folder3\..\folder2\..\folder1\file.dat
resolved: folder1/folder1/file.dat
original: \.\folder1\..\folder1\file.dat
resolved: folder1/file.dat
original: folder1\..\folder1\.\file.dat
resolved: folder1/file.dat
```

As our software is intended to be portable, we prefer `/` as directory separator. However, this can be easily adapted to work the opposite direction i.e. replacing initially every `/` by `\\` and use the latter exclusively.

IMHO, the most critical part are [UNC paths](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention). For our luck, our customers seem to understand them even less. At least, I never got any complaint about this (for years).

Re-reading the above linked Wikipedia article, I realized that URLs are mentioned also. *URLs are not handled correctly by this algorithm.*

Comment: thank you so much for providing this! This is what I imagined I would be implementing myself if no previous function existed. However,  @Retired Ninja has pointed me to `_fullpath()`, which will return both an absolute path and the relative path that I want, so I will be using this instead.

Comment: I noticed this also following the link of Retired Ninja. This is probably the better solution (to let the OS do it). I even consider to replace the code in our software there I derived the sample from. For a portable solution, I'd like to mention [SO: Safe cross-platform function to get normalized path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129096/safe-cross-platform-function-to-get-normalized-path) also.